# testing stripe purchase over $1000, stripe shows $1.00 charge

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Every purchase under $1000 shows the correct charge. It's only when there is a purchase over $1000 is when stripe shows a $1.00 charge. I understand that stripe charges by cents and I would have to multiply by 100 to convert to dollars. I don't know why this is happening.

```
$charge_amount = number_format($grand_total, 2)*100;


// Charge the user's card
try {
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
        "amount"        => $charge_amount,
        "currency"      => CURRENCY, //defined in another file
        "description"   => $description,
        "source"        => $token,
        "receipt_email" => $email,
        "metadata"      => $metadata)
);
```

Comment: How is that code supposed to help us help you?

Answer (score 2):

`number_format()` is for formatting numbers for display to humans. It does things like separating the every 3 digits with `,` characters. The Stripe API expects an actual number, and when it tries to parse this it stops at the comma.

If you just want to get a number with 2 decimal places, use `round()`, not `number_format()`.

```
$charge_amount = round($grand_total, 2) * 100;
```